# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python

I have this line of code

```
out_filename = os.path.join(self.save_dir, self.current_video + ".txt")
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> trackHelper.export_last_video()   File
> "C:\Users\Bharath\PointTrack\utils\mots_util.py", line 130, in
> export_last_video
> out_filename = os.path.join(self.save_dir, self.current_video + ".txt") TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and
> 'str'

Any help could be appeciated.

Comment: its mainly because the self.current_video is returning None, and you cannot concatenate strings with None

Comment: We can’t solve your problem, because you haven’t provided the code that sets `self.current_video` to None. Provide a [mcve] that generates error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.current_video` might be returning `None`. You can do something like this

```py
if self.current_video is not None:
    out_filename = os.path.join(self.save_dir, self.current_video + ".txt")
else:
    # handle the case where self.current_video is None
```

Comment: What if it's an int?

Comment: You can convert the int using the str() function.

Comment: Yes. I know very well what to do. My comment is to show that this answer is too general and such questions shouldn't be answered at all...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate String literals with None values hence you need to make sure that `self.current_video` doesn't return None.

As a precaution, you could always check whether it returns any other value than None, and then do the concatenation.

Comment: What if it's an int?

Comment: if its an int, the conversion to str has to be done to do the concatenation or else f strings gotta be used.

Comment: Yes. I know very well what to do. My comment is to show that this answer is too general and such questions shouldn't be answered at all...